# How to put contacts in the lower left corner of Thunderbird 3 main display?

Tags: thunderbird

How to put contacts in the lower left corner of Thunderbird 3 main display?
Like a box of contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see a way to do that with what's given, although there is a plugin that might be close to what you're looking for:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/70/